# How to upgrade Debian 6.0.7 to 7 without internet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, upgrade

I don't really know how to handle with linux as this Debian is my first ever installed. I've installed it on my laptop but unfortunately I have Realtek 8192SE wifi card which is not supported by squeeze so I can't get internet access. I didn't know that :/ Wheezy supports that card, so I wonder is that possible to burn boot CD/DVD of Debian 7 and upgrade mine system just from that disc?

Answer (score 0):

Steps are similar as for update from DVD. You must enable DVD in /etc/apt/sources.list a mount it on right path.

You can follow this [Debian wiki](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#cdroms), this link is for part about adding DVD config in sources.list. And next or previous steps you can find up on page.

Comment: However, reinstalling from a Wheezy CD or USB image might be easier and more reliable than an upgrade, especially if you don't have a lot in `/home` that you want to keep.

Comment: Maybe yes, but question is about upgrade.